# I need to refactor the javascript code(make it better, and smaller)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, refactoring

I have an html
with this structure

```
<table id="position_holder">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link1</a>
            <div class="question">question1</div>
            <div class="question">question2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link2</a>
            <div class="question">question3</div>
            <div class="question">question4</div>
            <div class="question">question5</div>
            <div class="question">question6</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and css makes div.question hidden
and i have a javascript witch need to become shoter(refract)

```
$('#position_holder td a').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).next('.question').text()) {
        alert('No test yet!');
    } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').text())) {
        if (!$(this).next('.question').next('.question').text()) {
            alert('TestSuccess!');
        } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').next('.question').text())) {
            if (!$(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text()) {
                alert('TestSuccess!');
            } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text())) {
                if (!$(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text()) {
                    alert('TestSuccess!');
                } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text())) {
                    if (!$(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text()) {
                        alert('TestSuccess!');
                    } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text())) {
                        if (!$(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text()) {
                            alert('TestSuccess!');
                        } else if (confirm($(this).next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').next('.question').text())) {
                            alert('Test Success!');
                        } else {
                            alert('Test Faluture');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Test Faluture');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Test Faluture');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Test Faluture');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Test Faluture');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Test Faluture');
    }
    return false;
});
```

This take a question one by one to user, first checkes if there is more questions, then if he select "chancel" the test over with falture alert, if he select ok, he pass to the next question

Please help me to do this more convinient way, i think this code is terrible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. This is basically doing the same thing as the code in question will fewer characters.

```
$('#position_holder td a').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).next('.question').text()) {
        alert('No test yet!');
    } else {

        var $questions = $(this).closest('td').find('.question');
        var questionCount = $questions.length;

        var count = 0;
        // Loop through all the questions
        $questions.each(function() {
            if (confirm($(this).text())) {
                if (++count === questionCount)
                    alert('TestSuccess!');
            } else {
                alert('Test Failure!');
                return false; // will break out of `each`
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It will check all the `.question` class div

Comment: Also skips the first question. Success is supposed to be alerted if all questions were confirmed, not if one wasnt.

Comment: @Mitul Thanks for notifying. Please check updated answer

Comment: Still the same issues as in my previous comment. You are skipping the first question and you are still calling success if the question wasn't confirmed.

Comment: Getting closer. `if (!confirm($(this).next('.question').text())) {` refers to the second question. The "Test Successful" is supposed to be called if all questions were confirmed. So you want `if (confirm($(this).text()))`.. If one single questions was not confirmed (else case) you show the Test failed alert and end the loop.

Comment: I'm getting notified to avoid discussions in comments, so I will leave one last message. `$(this)` in your each loop refers to the current question, `$(this).next('.question').text()` is therefore the next questions text. So your confirm dialog skips the first question. You need to change the confirm to `if (confirm($(this).text()))`. Also the question starter changed from li a to td a. (edit: just checked, works fine now)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#position_holder td a').on('click', function(){
    var question = $(this).next('.question');

    // check if the question has text
    if(!question.text()){
        alert('No test yet!');
        return;
    }

    // loop until test success or test failure
    while(true) {

        // confirm current question
        if(confirm(question.text())) {

            // take next question
            question = question.next('.question');

            // success if no text
            if(!question.text()){
                alert('TestSuccess!');
                break;
            }

            // continue if there is text
            continue;
        }

        // stop if confirm was canceled
        alert('Test Faluture');
        break;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xknufsq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hello i Cant find the #position_holder li in your html but here is the i have created script base on your HTML

```
$('table a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents("td").find(".question").each(function (index) {
        if(!confirm($(this).text())){
           alert('Test Failure');
           return false;
        }else{
           alert('Test Success !');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

WORKING DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/1gm7wj51/6/

Comment: and what about confirm messages to user? he must unswer every of it

Comment: @user14511 I have added confirm messages also updated in demo code new link http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/1gm7wj51/7/

Comment: for now it has "test success" on every test passed. Last else must replased with else if($(this).next().text() == ''){
              alert('Test Success !');
           }